# Why is my loop in JavaScript only returning the last value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

#### Background

I'm making a simple 2D [side-scroller game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-scrolling_video_game) using HTML/JavaScript, and using ES6 to manage my game-objects.

#### Code Design

I have 2 **arrays for each level platform** to track:

- `shortPlatform`
- `longPlatform`

For each *platform* there is a separate **loop to check for collisions** between the *player* object and respective *platform*.

However, the loop is **only allowing for collisions with the *last platform***.

---

Here is the code for my two loops:

```js
                for (let i = 0; i < shortPlatform.length; i++) 
                {
                    shortPlatform[i].renderObject();

                    // check if collide with players
                    var dir = colCheck(player, shortPlatform[i]);
                }

                for (let x = 0; x < longPlatform.length; x++) 
                {
                    longPlatform[x].renderObject();

                    // check if collide with players
                    var dir2 = colCheck(player, longPlatform[x]);
                };
```

#### Note

I've read through many of the other answers about closures here and can't seem to get any of the solutions working.

Comment: dir and dir2 are being overwritten in each step of the loop. You might want to use an array or a list to store those values

Answer (score 0):

Variable `dir` and `dir2` is local to your `for` loops. As a result, it's getting overwritten every time your loop iterates. Try using an array to store the occurrence of the collisions.